# How to fix gaps between laminate flooring and a door

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, wood-filler

We moved in to our house just before covid and had a trained "friend" fit our laminate flooring but since have come to realise he hasn't done a very good job and has stopped replying to messages.
Around our front and back door, there are gaps between the door and laminate flooring. What would be best to fill these? I am completely new to DIY so need as much help as possible!
Photos below.

Thanks,
Lauren
[image]

[image]

Comment: Other than the cut around the jamb that's really not looking painfully awful, and caulk or edge trim would fill and/or hide the small gap.

Comment: Your friend actually did a good job. The floor will expand/contract with temperature/humidity changes, etc. There should be a small gap to allow for that. You can cover with trim or maybe caulk.

Answer (score 2):

Are those sliding doors or regular hinged doors? The "friend" actually did a fairly good job of installing the flooring. There usually has to be a gap between the wall and flooring because the flooring will expand and contract if it's a floating floor. The gap is usually covered by molding fastened to the wall, not the floor. You can find different molding and trim at your home stores. They usually come in different colors or you can stain them to match.